# Taking inputs in two different while loops in one function does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

**I want to take inputs as long as the user enters '#' in `while` loops.**

I implemented the `while` algorithms seen below, and the first one actually works.  But the program does not enter the second `while` loop.  What I saw while debugging is that, in a function, only one `while(cin>> ....)` algorithm works, and it automatically ignores the second one.

Is there a solution to fix this?  How can I make the second `while` loop not be ignored?

```
void addTransaction(transactionNode* blockchain)
{
    string owner, sendTo="";
    int transactionId=0, outLocation=0, amount=0, tid;
    tid = blockchain->tid;
    transactionNode* newT = new transactionNode(++tid, owner, 0, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr); // created a empty transaction Node for the new transaction

    cout << "Input the owner of the transaction: " << endl;
    cin >> owner;
    newT->owner = owner; // updated the name

    cout << "Write the input list in form of 'transactionId_1 outLocation_1 transactionId_2 outLocation_2 #' put # after all the inputs finish: " << endl;
    while (cin>> transactionId >> outLocation) // takes the inputs until '#' is entered
    {
        insertAtEndforinputNode(newT->inputList, transactionId, outLocation); // adds the new input node to the end of the inputList in our current transaction
    }

    cout << "Write the output list in form of 'amount_1 sentTo_1 amount_2 sentTo_2 #' put # after all inputs finish: " << endl;
    while (cin>> amount>> sendTo) 
    {
        insertAtEndforoutputNode(newT->outputList, amount, sendTo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop is reading a pair of `int` values.  When it encounters the `#`, `operator>>` fails since `#` is not an integer, so `cin`'s error state is set, the loop stops, and the `#` is not extracted from `cin`.

The second loop is not entered because `cin` is still in an error state (and also because the `#` can't be read as an `int` anyway, so `operator>>` would just fail again).

Before you can enter the second loop, you need to call [`cin.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip the unread `#`, and also call [`cin.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) to reset the error state.